# Different marker colors for the same line

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to create a simple line graph for a webapp using plotly and dash. I want to a line connecting two points. I want one of the point tobe red and the other to be green. Here's what I have so far:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets = external_stylesheets)
graph = dcc.Graph(figure = {
    'data' : [
        go.Scatter(x = [1,4], y = [2,3], mode = 'lines+markers', opacity = 0.7, marker = {
            'size' : 15,
            'line' : {'width' : 0.5, 'color' : 'black'}
        })
    ]
})
app.layout = html.Div([graph])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug = False)
```

I am running this code in a Jupyter notebook with all the latest packages.
If I run this code, I get the line plot I want, but both the points are blue. I want the point corresponding to (1, 2) to be red and (4, 3) to be green. How can I go about doing this?
Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the accepted solution to this problem is to have 3 different `go.scatter()` objects in your graph data. One for the line, and one for each marker. Your app would end up looking like this:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets = external_stylesheets)
graph = dcc.Graph(figure = {
    'data' : [
        go.Scatter(x = [1,4], y = [2,3], mode = 'lines+markers', opacity = 0.7, 
                   marker={'color':["red","green"], "size":15})
    ]
})
app.layout = html.Div([graph])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug = False)
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your reply. That definitely seems to solve my problem. I wonder...is there another way to go about this? Plotting 3 times the number of graphs seems to be unnecessarily inefficient.

Comment: Oh, theres a much better way to do it. Sorry, I think you have to do different markers for different color bars. See my edited answer